# Express session works differently on localhost, android device, windows 10 and windows 7 or 8

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, passport.js, express-session

I have this single page application that makes 7 ajax http request when a user is successfully authenticated and redirected to the dashboard. When a user logs in passport authenticates and a session is created therefore redirects to the dashboard.When the dashboard loads it makes 7 ajax call to the server to get user data.On localhost it works fine but when this app was deployed on a remote cloud server, if i visit the site using android device like smart pad or windows 10 it still work as expected, But with windows 7 and 8 after successful authentication and redirection to the dashboard, those ajax call that suppose to get user data does not work. when i console the req.user on the remote server it says undefined within that endpoint.It seems session is unset or destroyed.

Here is the code

```js
'use strict';
require('dotenv').config();
var express = require('express');
var path = require("path");
var multer = require('multer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
   
var configuration = function (app,model) {
 //config
 var storeDB = process.env.MONGODB_ADDON_URI || "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb";
  var store = new MongoDBStore(
    {
      uri: storeDB,
      collection: 'mySessions'
  });
app.use('/assets',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
//middleware
app.use(cookieParser('anything'));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'anything',
  store: store,
  resave: true,   
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true, 
 originalMaxAge: 35999998,
    path: "/",
  } 
}));
 
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(multer({dest: './uploads'}).any());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.host);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-
  HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
 next();
  }
});
 
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {    
  done(null, user._id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {   
  model.user.findById(id, function(err, user) {
 done(err, user);
  });
});
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); 
app.use('/',router);

}

module.exports = {
  configuration: configuration,
  router: router,
  passport: passport 
}

//the login strategy
"use strict";
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
var path = require('path');
var config = require('./config');
var salt = require('./salt');
var router = config.router;
var passport = config.passport;  
 passport.use('user-login', new LocalStrategy({           
  usernameField : 'email',
  passwordField : 'password',
  passReqToCallback : true 
 },
 function (req, email, password, done) {         
  // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
  // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
  model.user.findOne({ email :  email }, function(err, user) {              
  // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
  if (err) {
    return done(err);
  }
  // if no user is found, return the message
  if (!user) {
    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); 
   // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
   }
   // if the user is found but the password is wrong
   if (!salt.isValidPassword(user,password)) {
     return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata
   }             
     return done(null, user);
   });

 }));

router.post('/user/login', passport.authenticate('user-login', {
  successRedirect : '/dashboard', // redirect to the secure profile section
  failureRedirect : '/failed', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
  failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}));

router.get('/dashboard',function(req,res){
  if(req.user){ 
   model.user.findOne({user_id: req.user.user_id},
   {presence:1,set_presence:1}).exec(function(err,data){
    data.presence = true;
    data.set_presence.general = true;
    data.save(function(err,info){
      console.log("presence is true");
    });
   });           
   res.json({
      isLoggedIn: true,
      typeOfUser: req.user.type,
      firstname: req.user.firstname,
      lastname:req.user.lastname,
      phone: req.user.phone,
      email: req.user.email,
      title: req.user.title,
      user_id: req.user.user_id,
      balance: req.user.ewallet.available_amount,
      profile_pic_url: req.user.profile_pic_url
      });
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }  
});

router.get("/dashboard/patient",function(req,res){ 
  if(req.user){
    res.render("patient",{"userInfo": req.user});
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }

});

router.get('/failed',function(req,res){        
    res.send(false);
})

//route
//user getting the available on the dashboard balance route.
 router.get('/dashboard/:userId/get-balance',function(req,res){
      console.log(req.user) //undefined
      if(req.user){
        model.user.findOne({user_id: req.params.userId},{ewallet:1},function(err,wallet){
          if(err) throw err;
          res.send({balance: wallet.ewallet.available_amount})
        })
      } else {
        res.send("Unauthorized access!!!")
      }
  });

//Angular code

app.controller('loginController',["$scope","$http","$location","$window","$resource","ModalService","templateService","localManager",
  "$rootScope","mySocket",function($scope,$http,$location,$window,$resource,ModalService,templateService,localManager,$rootScope,mySocket) {
  $scope.login = {};
  $scope.error = "";  
  
  $scope.send = function(){        
    var login = $resource('/user/login',null,{logPerson:{method:"POST",headers:{withCredentials: true}}});
    login.logPerson($scope.login,function(data){
    console.log(data) 
    localManager.setValue("resolveUser",data);
    //$rootScope.balance = data.balance;             
    if (data.isLoggedIn) {
       //user joins a room in socket.io and intantiayes his own socket
        switch(data.typeOfUser) {
          case "Patient":
            createAwareness(data)
            $window.location.href = '/dashboard/patient';   
          break;
          case "Doctor":
            createAwareness(data)
           $window.location.href = "/dashboard/doctor";   
          break;
          case "Pharmacy":
            $window.location.href = "/medical-center/pharmacy"; 
          break;          
          default:
            $window.location.href = "/medical-center/view"; 
          break; 

        }
        
      } else {       
        $scope.error = "Email or Password incorrect!";            
      }
    });
  }

  //this updates the current availability of user in real time.
  function createAwareness(data) {
    mySocket.emit("set presence",{status:"online",userId:data.user_id},function(response){
      if(response.status === true){
        if(data.typeOfUser === "Doctor"){
          mySocket.emit("doctor connect",{userId:data.user_id});
        } else if(data.typeOfUser === "Patient") {
          mySocket.emit("patient connect",data);
        }
      }
    });                                  
    
  }  
  
}]);

//one of the ajax get requests made from within dashboard as the page loads.
app.controller("balanceController",["$rootScope","$resource","localManager",function($rootScope,$resource,localManager){  
    var user = localManager.getValue("resolveUser");//this was set in the login controller
    var amount = $resource('/dashboard/:userId/get-balance',{userId: user.user_id});
    var wallet = amount.get(null,function(data){
     console.log(data) //"unauthorized access !!!"
      var format = "N" + data.balance.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      $rootScope.balance = format;
    })
}]);  
  

<!-- login form -->
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" ng-model = "login.email"   style="border: 1px solid rgba(0,255,0,0.8)">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model = "login.password" style="border: 1px solid rgba(0,255,0,0.8);margin: 10px 0px">
  <div style="text-align: center">
 <button class="btn btn-login" ng-click="send()" style="color: #fff;">LOGIN</button>
  </div>
  </form>
```

Please i need your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found what I was doing wrong. I did not specify the path in the cookie property of the option passed to the session to point to authentication route which is "/user/login".note by default path is "/".  I set path to be "/user" then I modified the request routes made through ajax call like so '/user/:userId/get-balance'. This actually did not create a new session or unset already existing session and it worked!